# Where to find sencha touch JSB file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to use spket plugin for code complete suggestions in eclipse using this tutorial : https://steve0hh.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/how-to-set-up-sencha-touch-code-assist-in-aptana/

The problem is that I cannot find jsb3 file in my downloaded sdk zip.

I am using sencha-touch-2.1.1-commercial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found the file which can be used :

http://dev.europalab.com/tizportdev/demos/Senchtest/touch.jsb3

Download this and put it into downloaded sencha touch folder(touch-2.1.1) as sibling of src folder and follow remaining steps as it is.

If above link is not working try this : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0EOCoTxRKgveFZlc2x2aDlpWFE/edit?usp=sharing