# Sencha Touch Integrated Development Environment (WebStorm)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, webstorm

I am new to Sencha Touch Framework. I am starting to develop a sencha touch application. I am stuck at using the right IDE for the development. Right now I am using Webstorm IDE for running the Sencha Touch Application. But I am not able to Debug the javascript which is not declared in HTML file.

As in Sencha Touch application there is a file app.js which is called from app.json file and not from index.html file. And WebStorm runs the index.html file and debug the javascript files which is not declared in it.

Can Anyone help me how I can debug javascript files in Sencha Touch Application using webstorm or suggest me proper IDE.

Thanks
Ishan jain

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to debug javascript code whether it is declared in index.html or not. To edit JS & HTML files you can choose any IDE of your liking (I use Eclipse. To enable autocomplete feature check out:  [Where to find sencha touch JSB file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182792/where-to-find-sencha-touch-jsb-file)).
If you are more comfortable using visual mode for generating code check out [Sencha Architect](http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/) which is full blown development tool for Sencha touch and ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets is an open source code editor for the web. It's built with JavaScript, HTML and CSS by web developers.

You can use 
[**Brackets**](http://download.brackets.io/)